# Web service hosted on EC2 host is not reachable from browser

Tags: web-services, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, flask-sqlalchemy, python-webbrowser

I hosted a Python/Flask web service on my Amazon (AWS) EC2 instance.  modified the security group rules such that All inbound traffic is allowed. 
I can login from ssh and ping(with public ip) is working fine but I couldn't open the service URL from the web browser. Could any one please suggest how can I debug this issue?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

It seems that web service isn't up and running or it is not listening on right port or it is listening just on 127.0.0.1 address. Check it with 'sudo netstat -tnlp' command. You should see process name, what IP and port it is listening on.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. Yes, indeed the service was just listening on 127.0.0.1 address. It's working fine after I change it to listen on all ports.